# Can you share any problems or inconveniences for ROS2?

Tags: ros2

Can you share any problems or inconveniences you have experienced while developing autonomous driving or mission planning software base on ROS2.

first, i would to design a framework based on the ROS2.
Basically follows a modular structure and identifies common inputs and outputs.

However, since ROS2 is used as the framework, scheduling will be done whit ROS2.
So my framework tries to develop a core that solves the problems that arise when developing ROS2 autonomous driving or mission planning software.

Therefore, I would like to identify and develop core that can alleviate some of the inconveniences and problems that you may have encountered while developing software based on ROS2.

Please share your insights

Thank you for your time

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Since you are planning to develop a framework based on ROS 2, I strongly suggest going through the following resources: https://design.ros2.org/